# Scripted dynamic update not working in ElasticSearch

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I am using the below code to update a document in elasticsearch

```
client.update({
   index: 'myindex',
   type: 'mytype',
   id: '1',
   body: {
     script: 'ctx._source.tags += tag',
     params: { tag: 'some new tag' }
   }
}, function (error, response) {

});
```

However, this throws a compile error. When I replace tag by `params.tag` above, it appends null to the present field i.e. identifies `params.tag` as `null`.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar confusion.  [This document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference-5-5.html#api-update-5-5) shares the example you have in your question.  On the other hand, [this document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/docs-update.html) shares a different example (which I got to work).

Your update statement would be something like this :

```
client.update({
    index: 'myindex',
    type: 'mytype',
    id: '1',
    body: {
        script: {
            inline: 'ctx._source.tags.add(params.tag)',
            lang: 'painless',
            params: { 
                tag: 'some new tag'
            }
        }
    }
}, function (error, response) {
    // handling of error/response
});
```

** Notice the `.add` instead of the `+=` for the case when adding to an array.